# Listview builder creating duplicate of list item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a list of widgets built using a listview builder. Problem is when i change the state of an item in the list(using the ontap property of the list item) the state changes quite alright but an exact replica of that mutated list item is added at the very top of my list

Snippet

```
List data = [1,2,2,1,1];

return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.builder(

        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          final s = data[index];

          return ListTile(

            dense: false,
            leading: leading(leading),
            title: Text(s),
            subtitle: Text(
              "${s}",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {//do something to the subtitle});
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving every`ListTile` a unique `Key`

For example:

```
     return ListTile(
        key: Key("${index}"),
        dense: false,
        leading: leading(leading),
        title: Text(s),
        subtitle: Text(
          "${s}",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {//do something to the subtitle});
        },
      );
```

Comment: could you tell me where is you data variable declared?